# 2D - 3D - 2D projection

Tags: python, image-processing, 3d, computer-vision, 2d

I have an image with its depth map and intrinsics matrix K, I'm trying to do 2D to 3D reprojection of the image using the camera matrix formula, I have done the reprojection, but to make sure that I did it correctly I'm trying to reproject the image from 3D to 2D to verify that the reprojection is being done correctly, but I get an image with a lot of distortion lines, horizontally and vertically, I have doubt that these distortion lines are coming from 0 values in the depth map but I'm not sure.
can you help me, please?
Here is the code I'm using in Python:

```
# Load depth map
left_depth_map = np.loadtxt('Photometric_Stereo\data\example\depth_left.txt', delimiter=',')

# Find the maximum depth value
max_depth = np.max(left_depth_map)

# Replace the missing depth values with zero
left_depth_map[left_depth_map < 1] = 1

# Normalize the depth map to the range [0, 1]
left_depth_map /= max_depth

# Define camera intrinsic matrix K
K = np.array([[576, 0, 511.5],
              [0, 576, 217.5],
              [0, 0, 1]])

# Initialize empty arrays for 3D points and corresponding 2D points
points_3d = []
points_2d = []

# Perform 2D-3D reprojection
height, width = left_depth_map.shape
for v in range(height):
    for u in range(width):
        depth = left_depth_map[v, u]
        if depth > 0:
            point_3d = np.linalg.inv(K) @ np.array([u, v, 1]) * depth
            point_2d = K @ (point_3d / point_3d[2])
            points_3d.append(point_3d)
            points_2d.append(point_2d[:2])

# Convert the lists of points to NumPy arrays
points_3d = np.array(points_3d)
points_2d = np.array(points_2d)

# Perform 3D-2D reprojection
reprojected_2d = []
for i in range(points_3d.shape[0]):
    point_2d = K @ (points_3d[i] / points_3d[i, 2])
    reprojected_2d.append(point_2d[:2])
reprojected_2d = np.array(reprojected_2d)

# Load the original image
left_image = cv2.imread('Photometric_Stereo\data\example\im_left.jpg')

# Create a blank image with the same size and channels as the original image
synthesized_image = np.zeros_like(left_image)

# Copy RGB values from the original image to the synthesized image based on the reprojected 2D coordinates
for i, point in enumerate(reprojected_2d):
    x, y = point.astype(int)
    if 0 <= x < synthesized_image.shape[1] and 0 <= y < synthesized_image.shape[0]:
        synthesized_image[y, x] = left_image[y, x]

# Display the synthesized image
cv2.imshow("Synthesized Image", synthesized_image)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Here is the original image:
[image]

And the depth image:
[image]

And the 2D-3D-2D image I get using the code:
[image]

Comment: You’re not interpolating at all? The black lines are output pixels that you haven’t assigned a value to, I guess. Usually you’d loop over the output pixels, and find the corresponding input coordinate for each, and find the input value for those coordinates (by interpolation, even if it’s nearest neighbor interpolation).

Comment: it's going to be hard to interpolate a bunch of points you're projecting. you'd have to draw each as a small circle, not just a single pixel. either that, or you interpret that depth map as a mesh, slap the picture on it as a texture, and use a proper 3D graphics library to rasterize the result. that is now capable of doing proper interpolation.

Comment: as for these gaps: numerics. see that you _round_ instead of truncating. your `x, y = point.astype(int)` should work better as `x, y = point.round().astype(int)`, but no guarantees. if the actual calculations contain enough numerical error, you'll still get issues.

Comment: what you see is an aliasing effect, related to moire patterns. when you actually change the viewpoint, you'll see a lot clearer what's going on. for a start, change the focal length to shrink the picture or enlarge it. next, move the camera into the scene a little bit.

Comment: would you like that turned into an answer that you can mark as accepted? or have you moved on from this question?

Comment: The solution of rounding the points did work!
Thx, you can mark this answer as accepted.

Comment: That can only be done by the one who asked the question. Feel free to do so. The reasoning is explained in the [tour]. I've posted my comments as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are projecting each point and then drawing it as a pixel. This is not amenable to interpolation. You would need to have a textured mesh instead. That can be drawn nicely with any 2D/3D graphics library (OpenGL, D3D, ...).

The gaps between your individually drawn *points* are due to numerics.

Small numerical errors happen (and accumulate) due to the finite precision of numbers.

Your `x, y = point.astype(int)` is always truncating. Say a coordinate is calculated to be `6.999999`. Truncation results in `6.0`, and now you've got almost an entire pixel of error.

You should *round* before converting:

```
x, y = point.round().astype(int)
```

That isn't guaranteed to fix all issues. It *will* give you less error in your results, and it should work well for the case of *no* viewpoint change.

The gaps you see are an aliasing effect (from the truncation), related to moiré patterns. When you actually change the viewpoint, you'll see a lot clearer what's going on. For a start, you could change the focal length to shrink the picture or enlarge it, then try moving the camera into the scene a little bit. Then you'll see that you actually have a point cloud, not a textured mesh.